# Python flask - how to make it so there can't be duplicate usernames registered in the MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, database, authentication, flask

I'm really new to this stuff. I want to make it so that there can't be 2 duplicate or same usernames on the database. For example, if I register once with the username 'johndoe' and register again with the same username, it also gets registered in the database which I don't want to happen. I want so if the username exists, return 'unsuccessful' or something like that for now.

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "abcd"
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'Root123'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'login'

mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            loginUsername = request.form['login_username']
            loginPassword = request.form['login_password']
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE Username=%s AND Password=%s", (loginUsername, loginPassword))
            loginInfo = cursor.fetchone()
            if loginInfo is not None:
                return "yes"
            else:
                return "no"
    return render_template("login.html")


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userDetails = request.form
        username = userDetails['register_username']
        email = userDetails['register_email']
        password = userDetails['register_password']
        userID = str(uuid.uuid4())
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO logininfo(username, email, password, userID) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (username, email, password, userID))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("register.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you have two options:

1. Make the verification exclusively in your Flask application code.
2. Use database features to block duplicate users to be inserted (e.g. add a unique key constraint on the `username` attribute).

If you're going to use 2) you need to handle in your Flask code the error returned by the DBMS when it detects that someone is trying to add a new row with an existing `username` value.

Otherwise, for option 1), you could do something similar to what you do in your login route:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM logininfo WHERE Username=%s", (username,))
existingInfo = cursor.fetchone()
if existingInfo is not None:
   return "Error: user is already registered"  # or render_template a special error template.
```

Comment: tried this before and got an error, tried this again right now and im still getting the same error:     
raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Comment: Sorry, I missed a small detail. The second argument passed to execute (`(username,)`) has to be iterable, so we use either a list or a tuple. In order to create a tuple with a single element, we need to add a comma after it. So change `cursor.execute("...", (username))` to `cursor.execute("...", (username,))`. I also edited the answer. I hope this fixes it

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I actually recently figured that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When creating the table use the `unique` constraint.  Here is an example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (id int primary key, username varchar(255), pass_hash varchar(255), UNIQUE(username))
```

This will raise an error stating that the inserted value is a duplicate.  Handle the error using some try except code.